# How to create ArrayAddition function using dart

Tags: dart

What is the right syntax in `dart` for the below `js` code:

I am trying to create a function `ArrayAddition(arr)` take the array
of numbers stored in `arr` and return the string true if any combination of numbers
in the array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array, otherwise
return the string false. For example: if arr contains `[4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3]` the
output should return true because `4 + 6 + 10 + 3 = 23`.

```
function ArrayAddition(arr) { 

  arr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
  var maxNum = arr.pop();
  var tot = 0;
    
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    tot += arr[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
      if (i != j) {
        tot += arr[j];
        if (tot == maxNum) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
      
    for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
      if (i != k) {
        tot -= arr[k];
        if (tot == maxNum) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    tot = 0;
  }
    
  return false; 
         
}
```

So what is the rightt syntax for this in `dart` language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost the exact same code, just change the following lines:

```js
function ArrayAddition(arr) {
```

to

```dart
bool ArrayAddition(List<int> arr) {
```

---

```js
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
```

to

```dart
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

---

```js
var maxNum = arr.pop();
```

to

```dart
var maxNum = arr.removeLast();
```